# MySQL cannot connect to XAMPP vm on MacOS

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp-vm

I recently downloaded XAMPP 7.4 vm for Mac OS Monterey, and I had no problem with starting the server, and Apache, MySQL, and ProFTPD were all green. Until recently, MySQL started turning yellow and then turn red after a bit, and it wouldn't allow me to access the PhpMyAdmin on the browser. I check the log in XAMPP and it gives me this error message: ERROR: Failed to start "mysql": cannot start service: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 263: kill: No such process

The PhpMyAdmin give me this error:
[image: PhpMyAdmin error]

I try delete and reinstall XAMPP but it still didn't work. I try changing the port number but also didn't work. I kill process on activity monitor then try to reopen again but also didn't work.

Comment: phpMyAdmin won't be able to connect if MySQL isn't running, you'll have to figure out what's happening there before you can use phpMyAdmin. I'd try to reboot the computer first, check to make sure you only have one XAMPP installation, and try to start MySQL again from the XAMPP interface. You can then examine the error log and report back here what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ' ';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).